# How does Visual Studio know where referenced DLL solutions are?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have two solutions, Solution A and Solution B.

I compiled a DLL from Solution A and copied it into a folder in Solution B.  Then I referenced that DLL in a project in Solution B.  Didn't copy any PDB files over.

While I was debugging, I was able to step in to code in the DLL which references Solution A.  It opens up the source file and the path is exactly the same as the folder to Solution A (i.e. C:\Work\Solution A\SomeFile.cs)

How does visual studio know this?

Comment: The debugger has no trouble finding the PDB, and thus the source files as well, the path to the PDB is embedded in the DLL.  The Release build version of the PDB omits this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you look, there is nothing telling your project that it is in a certain DLL. So you compile and it comes to linking you end up with unresolved symbols. This is actually expected. When a DLL is part of a solution then it does it automatically through the ***Link Dependant Libraries***.

When you build the DLL you should notice a file with the .lib extension. This is your label. If you add this to your project as a linker input then your project will find the symbols defined inside your DLL and compile properly.

Take a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx

Comment: This is a C# question (note the file name), there is no .lib file.